# Storing python output to variables in Wolfram

Tags: functions, export, programming, output, python

Would like to use the external language input in python to save variables I can potentially use in Mathematica. Any chance there is a way to do this?

I do understand there might be a solution with using ExternalEvaluate but might there be a function built in the python wolframclient that assigns an object to a Wolfram data type?

It would be nice to run some data heavy code in python and then use the output with Wolfram in Mathematica.